# meaning of "to go by six-forty-five"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> But she doesn’t really believe these silent Saturday-morning appearances have anything
>   to do with early-onset Alzheimer’s; on any given weekday morning Harvey Stevens is
>   ready and raring **to go by six-forty-five**, a man of sixty who looks fifty (well, fifty-four)
>   in either of his best suits, and who can still cut a trade, buy on margin, or sell short with
>   the best of them.

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase in bold, does it refer to age and mean: when he become sixty years old or fifty or forty years old?

This passage is from a short story named: Harvey's Dream By Stephen King.

Answer (score 3):

"Six forty-five" is the time: 6:45 in the morning.

"Raring to go" is an idiom meaning "ready, eager".

Comment: Lots of thanks, so it means: at this time he is ready and eager to go and begin  his duties. am I right?

Comment: That's right, @ViserHashemi